What is the least redundant way I can write partially overlapping sets of conditions in Python?
I have a code where many combinations of conditions (some parts of which are repeated) lead to the same outcome. For example:
if (A and Y and a) or (B and Y and b) or (C and c):
    run() 

I feel logically it must be possible to write these combinations in one readable statement that doesn't repeat any conditions.
Imagine Y is an expensive (or verbose) function, so I don't want to execute it (or write it) twice.
Also, suppose the order of checking these conditions matters. A/B needs to be checked before Y, which needs to be checked before a/b.
If order didn't matter, I could write:
if (A and a or B and b) and Y or (C and c):
    run()

If A was guaranteed to return True, I could store the result of Y the first time I compute it:
if (A and (isY:=Y) and a) or (B and isY and b) or (C and c):
    run() 

If I knew that Y would need to be computed in every case, I could precompute it:
isY=Y
if (A and isY and a) or (B and isY and b) or (C and c):
    run() 

If A, B, and C weren't expensive, I could check them twice:
if (A or B) and Y or (C and c):
    if (A and a) or (B and b) or C:
        run() 

But supposing order matters, and all condition checks are non-guaranteed and expensive:
How can I pythonically write these overlapping conditions so that each condition is checked (and ideally run() is written) only once?

Evaluate the values only once if and when needed. For example, in your first example, if Y is False, then you don't care what A,a,B, or b are.

For this question Y can only be checked after A (or B). For instance, A might be something like (type(x) is int) and Y is (x<4), which crashes for x not comparable with 4. Except more expensive than that. (Or the order may be for optimization reasons, like Y is more expensive than A and B, so it'd be preferred to check if they're false first.)
